# Вопрос о слове "ночью"

Tags: части-речи

*Даже **ночью** муравьишка не пропустит свой домишко.*

Здесь слово "ночью" — это существительное или наречие?
А **"-ю"** — это суффикс или окончание?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Информация из словаря на Грамоте.ру:

НОЧЬЮ, нареч. В ночное время. Ночью пошёл дождь.

Таким образом, форма существительного в Т.п. *ночью* переходит в наречие, а окончание Ю становится суффиксом.